# How to handle submitted array of json with fosrest bundle and nemio api doc bundle

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle

I have a controller in my Rest API that expects an array of json (in POST)

```
   {
       data: [
            {
              name: "marc"
            },
            {
              name: "john"
            }
          ]
    }
```

Submitted data are then saved in database.
I don't know what annotation to use in order to tell "nelmio api doc bundle" to generate the appropriate html page in order to have capability to test my API by creating multiple items (an array of items). 
To resume the question is : Can nelmio documentation generates a dynamic collection of forms ?

Answer (score 0):

You can test your API through nelmio sandbox.

Nelmio have the "New Parameter" button which is can add multiple key => value parameters.